# $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{a_n}.$ Find the limit.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{a_n}.$

Is $a_n$ convergent?

How could i find its limit?

I found even terms of the sequence decrease and odd terms are increase. But i cant find upper and lower bounds to use monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Here is one hint: If the limit exists (call it $A$), then $A=1+1/A$. Can you see why? Oh, and one more question: Was a value for $a_1$ (or $a_0$) given?

Comment: $a_1=1$ Ok but how could i find the sequences $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ approaches to same limit?

Comment: You could show the sequence is contractive: $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|\le C|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ with $0<C<1$. (Note this, by itself, would imply the sequence converges.)

Comment: As for the bounds: there is an obvious lower bound. Once you've found that, there is an almost as obvious upper bound.

Comment: first prove $a_n\in(1,2)$ then we can use high-low limit to prove it's convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who knows derived following criteria may apply:

If $f:I \rightarrow I$ is differentiable and $p$ is a fixed point such that $f'(p) <1$ then the sequence given by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ este converges to $p$.

For $$f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty),f(x)=1+\frac{1}{x},f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2},p=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, |f'(p)|=\frac{2}{3+\sqrt{5}}<1.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can prove by induction that
$$a_n = \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$$
where $\{F_n\}_{n\geq 1}=\{1,1,2,3,5,8,\ldots\}$ is the Fibonacci sequence.

Binet formula hence gives:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n = \phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$